# How go through all tabales in databases UserId - X. Procedure

Tags: mysql, search, procedure

How can I go through all the tables in database because I want find specific number of UserId where X - its a number UserId example X = 2 so I must find UserId = 2

I use MySQL and I want create procedure

Schema of my database:

```
Something ( ... ) --> without UserId
Something1 (... , UserId,...)
Something2 (... , UserId,...)
Something3 (... , UserId,...)
Cat
Cat1
Cat2
Cat3
Cat4
etc....
```

Table without number maybe we call PARENT and tables with number example (Cat1, Cat2... Cat3..) we call CHILDREN>

CHILDREN are created dynamically when we got 20000 records in one table

I want call procedure example:  CALL SearchUser(X) where X - number of UserId

If somebody have a script I will be grateful or If somebody help me also

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is working. Please try it out.
The db name is hardcorded here `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('test')`

```
## Procedure for search in all fields of all databases
DELIMITER $$
#Script to loop through all tables using Information_Schema
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_table $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_table(in_search varchar(50),in_column_name varchar(50))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE trunc_cmd VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE search_string VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE db,tbl,clmn CHAR(50);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE COUNTER INT;
DECLARE table_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT concat('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM `',table_schema,'`.`',table_name,'` WHERE `', in_column_name,'` = "',in_search,'"') ,table_schema,table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('test') and column_name=in_column_name ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
#Truncating table for refill the data for new search.
PREPARE trunc_cmd FROM "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_details;";
EXECUTE trunc_cmd ; 
OPEN table_cur;
table_loop:LOOP
FETCH table_cur INTO search_string,db,tbl,clmn;
#Executing the search
SET @search_string = search_string;
SELECT  search_string;
PREPARE search_string FROM @search_string;
EXECUTE search_string;
SET COUNTER = @CNT_VALUE;
SELECT COUNTER;
IF COUNTER>0 THEN
# Inserting required results from search to table
INSERT INTO temp_details VALUES(db,tbl,clmn);
END IF;
IF done=1 THEN
LEAVE table_loop;
END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE table_cur;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Temp table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_details` ( 
`t_schema` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`t_table` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`t_field` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Calling procedure:

```
call get_table('2','userID');
select * from temp_details;
```

Comment: ok procedure it works but I want only call searchUser(X)

your call get_table... doesnt work --> search_string NULL

In parameters I must define only INT UserId = INT

temp_details its NOT OK because I want information about Columns from Cat1, Cat2, Cat3 ... where is UserId and his/her other columns